# Why can't I change page after submitting form?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I should see: "Hello" after hitting submit, but I don't. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/GbfLG/1/

```
<div data-role="page" id="create">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("HERE");
      $('#form').submit(function() {
      $.post("/").success(function(resp) {
        alert("RET");
        $.mobile.changePage($("#final"));
      });
      return false;
      });
    </script>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="form">
            <input type="submit" name="g" value="Submit" id="g"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="final">
   Hello
</div>​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQM has a different set of rules then the normal web page. You have used your java script in the wrong place. With jQM, if possible write all you js code in separate file/files.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/993Kd/) is a fix made to your jsFiddle code, it is working now, I have just put it in right context. Your js code was not changed a bit.

Example:

```
$('#create').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){        
    $('#form').submit(function() {    
        $.post("/").success(function(resp) {
            $.mobile.changePage($("#final"));
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submiting - the `return false;` isn't working as it should.
Try..

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    ... stuff ...
});
```

Also in your fiddle you haven't defined $.changePage so it comes out as 'undefined'.